# Node.js promise fails intermittently, even when handled

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, promise

I'm learning to use MongoDB by creating a simple blog app. However, a portion of my code that saves a given post seems to give problems with promises occasionally, but not always, and whether the code succeeds simply seems to be luck.

Each post in my database is stored with the following schema:

```
{
    title: String,
    author: String,
    body: String,
    slug: String,
    baseSlug: String,
    published: { type: Boolean, default: false }
}
```

The `slug` defines the link used to access the blog post, and is automatically generated based upon the title of the blog post. However, if article titles are duplicates, the `slug` will have a number added to the end to differentiate it from similar articles, while the `baseSlug` will remain the same. For example:

- I create the post `"My first post"`, and it is assigned the `baseSlug` of `"my-first-post"`. Because no other posts have the same `baseSlug`, the `slug` is also set to be `"my-first-post"`.
- I create another post called `"My first post"`, and it is assigned the `baseSlug` of `"my-first-post"`. However, because another post has the same `baseSlug`, it is assigned the `slug` `"my-first-post-1"`.

To create this behavior, I wrote the following `addpost` route in Express:

```
app.post("/addpost", (req, res) => {
    let postInfo = req.body;

    for (key of Object.keys(postInfo)) {
        if (postInfo[key] == "true") postInfo[key] = true;
    }

    let slug = postInfo.title
        .toLowerCase()
        .split(" ")
        .filter(hasNumber) // return /\d/.test(str);
        .slice(0, 5)
        .join("-");
    postInfo.slug = slug;

    var postData;

    Post.find({ baseSlug: postInfo.slug }, (error, documents) => {
        if (documents.length > 0) {
            let largestSlugSuffix = 0;

            for (let document of documents) {
                var fullSlug = document.slug.split("-");
                var suffix = fullSlug[fullSlug.length - 1];
                if (!isNaN(suffix)) {
                    if (parseInt(suffix) > largestSlugSuffix) {
                        largestSlugSuffix = suffix;
                    }
                }
            }

            largestSlugSuffix++;
            postInfo.baseSlug = postInfo.slug;
            postInfo.slug += "-" + largestSlugSuffix;
        } else {
            postInfo.baseSlug = postInfo.slug;
        }

        postData = new Post(postInfo);
    })
        .then(() => {
            postData
                .save()
                .then(result => {
                    res.redirect("/");
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(400).send("Unable to save data");
                });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(400).send("Unable to save data");
        });
});
```

This code seems to work most of the time, but sometimes it fails, and outputs the following:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined
    at C:\Users\User\BlogTest\app.js:94:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
```

(For reference, line 94 in my file is `postData.save()`)

I suspect it is because the main body of the function takes longer than it should to execute, and the `postData` variable is not yet defined. However, `postData.save()` should not be executed until the promise finishes, because of the `.then()` callback function.

Why is my code behaving like this? Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are mixing promises with callbacks and closures. That's not how this is intended to work.

When you chain promises, whatever you return in the first promise handler will be added as an input to the next one. And if you return a promise, that promise will be resolved first before being sent to the next thenable.

So you need to return promises from your promises, like this:

```
app.post("/addpost", (req, res) => {
  let postInfo = req.body;

  for (key of Object.keys(postInfo)) {
    if (postInfo[key] == "true") postInfo[key] = true;
  }

  let slug = postInfo.title
    .toLowerCase()
    .split(" ")
    .filter(hasNumber) // return /\d/.test(str);
    .slice(0, 5)
    .join("-");
  postInfo.slug = slug;

  // var postData; <-- Don't do that

  Post.find({ baseSlug: postInfo.slug })
    .then((documents) => {
      if (documents.length > 0) {
        let largestSlugSuffix = 0;

        for (let document of documents) {
          var fullSlug = document.slug.split("-");
          var suffix = fullSlug[fullSlug.length - 1];
          if (!isNaN(suffix)) {
            if (parseInt(suffix) > largestSlugSuffix) {
              largestSlugSuffix = suffix;
            }
          }
        }

        largestSlugSuffix++;
        postInfo.baseSlug = postInfo.slug;
        postInfo.slug += "-" + largestSlugSuffix;
      } else {
        postInfo.baseSlug = postInfo.slug;
      }
      return new Post(postInfo);
      // We could actually have called postData.save() in this method,
      // but I wanted to return it to exemplify what I'm talking about
    })
    // It is important to return the promise generated by postData.save().
    // This way it will be resolved first, before invoking the next .then method
    .then( (postData) => { return postData.save(); })
    // This method will wait postData.save() to complete
    .then( () => { res.redirect("/"); })
    .catch( (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(400).send("Unable to save data");
    });
});
```

It can be greatly simplified with async/await:

```
app.post("/addpost", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let postInfo = req.body;

    for (key of Object.keys(postInfo)) {
      if (postInfo[key] == "true") postInfo[key] = true;
    }

    let slug = postInfo.title
      .toLowerCase()
      .split(" ")
      .filter(hasNumber)
      .slice(0, 5)
      .join("-");
    postInfo.slug = slug;

    let documents = await Post.find({ baseSlug: postInfo.slug });
    if (documents.length > 0) {
      let largestSlugSuffix = 0;

      for (let document of documents) {
        var fullSlug = document.slug.split("-");
        var suffix = fullSlug[fullSlug.length - 1];
        if (!isNaN(suffix)) {
          if (parseInt(suffix) > largestSlugSuffix) {
            largestSlugSuffix = suffix;
          }
        }
      }
      largestSlugSuffix++;
      postInfo.baseSlug = postInfo.slug;
      postInfo.slug += "-" + largestSlugSuffix;
    } else {
      postInfo.baseSlug = postInfo.slug;
    }
    let postData = new Post(postInfo);
    await postData.save();
    res.redirect("/");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).send("Unable to save data");
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I found the async/await solution elegant and intuitive. Accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing callbacks and promises and while it may do something, I'm not sure what it will do exactly. You should pick one or the other and not mix them as much as possible. I would recommend picking promises if you are using a language that supports async/await, otherwise callbacks.

So for example your outter handler could be an async function

```js
app.post("/addpost", async (req, res) => {
  //...
})
```

Your real bug is in handling `Post.find` you are handling it somewhat with a callback and somewhat with a promise, and probably whats happening is that its random which one will get called first the callback or the promise resolution. Instead of both you should just do this now that you have an async function:

```js
try {
  const posts = await Post.find({ baseSlug: postInfo.slug });

  // stuff you were doing in the callback
  const post = new Post(postInfo)
  
  // Now the promise code
  await post.save()

  // success!
  res.redirect("/");

} catch (err) {
  // With an async function you can just catch errors like normal
  console.log(err);
  res.status(400).send("Unable to save data");
}
```

If you're not using webpack or typescript and cannot target es7 then and thus cannot use async/await then I would recommend just using callbacks, do not use `.then` or `.catch` and that would look more like:

```js
function error(err) {
  console.log(err)
  res.status(400).send("Unable to save data")
}

Post.find({ baseSlug: postInfo.slug }, (err, documents) => {
  if (err) return error(err)

  // stuff you're doing in the callback now
  const post = new Post(postInfo)

  post.save((err) => {
    if (err) return error(err)
    
    // success!
    res.redirect("/");
  })
})
```